# how to scroll the text in the notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to scroll the text title in the notification bar and the data is coming from inside the App.
`NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channel);
        builder.setContentTitle(data);
        Notification notification=builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0,notification);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use bigText for long text which will be scrollable. **longText** will be text which will be scrollable.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channel);
        builder.setContentTitle(data);
        builder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
         .bigText(longText))
        Notification notification=builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0,notification);
```

Check this link for more details : [Click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle)

Comment: I have done this but this truncates the string to next line but I want to scroll

Comment: Anyone, please tell me the how to scroll the text in a notification, please it's urgent